# Handle condition within Pipe RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have this kind of `Observable` and I can easily use the `async` pipe on the template with this.

```
leadChanged$: Observable<LeadModel>;

this.leadChanged$ = this.leadsDataService.leadChanged$.pipe(
          map((res) => ({
            ...res,
            alert: { ...res.alert, transcript: highlightKeywordsLeadFunction(this.lead) },
          }))     
        );
```

But due to extra logic where now I need to write above like so: The logic is this `res?.isManualLead`. Do you know how to use this without a `subscribe` here? i.e. I want to use the `async` pipe here too.

```
leadChanged: LeadModel;

this.leadsDataService.leadChanged$
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res?.isManualLead) {
          this.leadChanged = {
            ...res,
          };
        } else {
          this.leadChanged = {
            ...res,
            alert: { ...res.alert, transcript: highlightKeywordsLeadFunction(this.lead) },
          };
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about condition inside the map operator?

```js
this.leadChanged$ = this.leadsDataService.leadChanged$.pipe(
  map(res => res?.isManualLead
    ? { ...res } 
    : { ...res, alert: { ...res.alert, transcript: highlightKeywordsLeadFunction(this.lead) } }
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to first or second observable based on a condition sing
[iif](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif) rxjs operator

```
import { iif, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

this.leadsDataService.leadChanged$.pipe(
  mergeMap((res) => iif(() => res?.isManualLead, of({ ...res }), of(anotherValue)))
);
```